# Micro-operations on an EXECUTE cycle of an instruction

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers

Here is the instruction: **MAC #NUM, (R0)+, R1** which translates to the following:

**MAC source1, source2, source3/destination**,

in other words, it does the following:

**source3/destination <--- (source1 x source 2) + source3/destination**.

This instruction is to be executed on a single-bus cpu internal organization:

[image: Single-bus CPU organization]

The question asks to give the sequence of control steps to execute this instruction (only the execute phase).

The solution that was given was

```
T3: load TEMP with immediate data #NUM 
    BUS <- IR(immediate data field), TEMP <- Bus

T4: get the operand pointed to by R0 from memory into MDR and increment value of R0:

    Bus <- R0, MDR <- BUS, Sel_temp = 1, F =ADD, result <- alu output

T5: READ, MDR <- data_out_of_memory, BUS <- result, R0 <- Bus

T6: perform the multiply of #NUM X MEM(R0)
    Bus <- MDR, sel_temp = 0, F = multiply, result <- alu out

T7: save result of multiplication into the TEMP 

    BUS <- Result, TEMP <- Result

T8: add R1 to TEMP
    BUS <- R1, F = ADD, sel_temp = 0, result <- alu output

T9: store final result back into R1

    Bus <= Result, R1 <- Bus, END.
```

My question is, why is it that they're throwing `R0` register in the `MDR` instead of the `MAR`? Don't you need to put something in the MAR if you're planning on retrieving data from the memory at `T5`?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, that should be `MAR <- R0`

Comment: @Jester that's what I thought...